# Creating a packet as a string and then extracted its fields in C

Tags: sockets, udp, byte, fwrite, fread

I need to implement my own packets to send over UDP. I decided that I would do this by sending a char buffer which has the sequence number, checksum, size, and the data of the packet which is bytes from a file. The string i'm sending separates each field by a semicolon. Then, when I receive the string (which is my packet) I want to extract each felid, use them accordingly (the sequence number, size, and checksum) and write the bytes to a file. So far I have wrote a method to create 100 packets, and I'm trying to extract and write the bytes to a file (I'm not doing it in the receiver yet, first I'm testing the parsing in the sender). For some reason, the bytes written to  my file are incorrect and I'm getting "JPEG DATATSTREAM CONTAINS NO IMAGE" error when I try to open it.

```
struct packetNode{
    char packet[1052]; // this is the entire packet data including the header
    struct packetNode *next;
};
```

This is how I'm creating my packets:

```
//populate initial window of size 100

    for(i = 0; i < 100; i++){
      memset(&data[0], 0, sizeof(data));
      struct packetNode *p; // create packet node
      p = (struct packetNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct packetNode));
      bytes = fread(data, 1, sizeof(data), fp); // read 1024 bytes from file into data buffer
       int b = fwrite(data, 1, bytes, fpNew);

      printf("read: %d\n", bytes);
      memset(&p->packet[0], 0, sizeof(p->packet));
      sprintf(p->packet, "%d;%d;%d;%s", s, 0, numPackets, data); // create packet

      //calculate checksum
      int check = checksum8(p->packet, sizeof(p->packet));
      sprintf(p->packet, "%d;%d;%d;%s", s, check, numPackets, data); //put checksum in packet
      s++; //incremenet sequence number



      if(i == 0){
            head = p;
            tail = p;
            tail->next = NULL;
        }
        else{
            tail->next = p;
            tail = p;
            tail->next = NULL;
        }


    }
  fclose(fp);
```

and this is where I parse and write the bytes to a file:

```
void test(){
 FILE *fpNew = fopen("test.jpg", "w");
 struct packetNode *ptr = head;
 char *tokens;


 int s, c, size;
 int i = 0;
 char data[1024];

  while(ptr != NULL){
    memset(&data[0], 0, sizeof(data));
    tokens = strtok(ptr->packet,";");
    s = atoi(tokens);
    tokens = strtok(NULL, ";");
    c =  atoi(tokens);
    tokens = strtok(NULL, ";");
    size = atoi(tokens);
    tokens = strtok(NULL, ";");

    if(tokens != NULL)
    strcpy(data, tokens);

    printf("sequence: %d, checksum: %d, size: %d\n", s,c,size);
    int b = fwrite(data, 1, sizeof(data), fpNew);

    ptr = ptr->next;
   i++;
  }

fclose(fpNew);
}
```

Comment: Could you post your `struct packetNode`? You would need a [`#pragma pack(1)`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure-Packing-Pragmas.html).

Comment: I updated my code. I don't want to send the struct over the stream, just the field packet[1052]

Comment: Ok, bad guess. Maybe add a `;` to the `sprintf`s.? You strtok for it 4 times, there's only 3 in the packet header; it might try to find the 4th somewhere in the JPEG data. (also a guess ;-))

Comment: Hm, could it be you `strcopy( data, tokens );` which is not binary safe (it stops at the first 0 in the JPEG stream). Maybe `memcpy( data, tokens, size)`, or just `fwrite( tokens, 1, size, fpNew)`?

Comment: still the same results

Comment: Could you update the post with the new code?

Comment: One thing I missed: you also `sprintf(p->packet, "%d;%d;%d;%s", s, check, numPackets, data);`, thus treating `data` as a string.

Comment: How can I make data bytes again when I extract it from the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is transfer of binary data, a JPEG stream, this data cannot be treated as a string. It's better to go all binary. For instance, instead of

```
  sprintf(p->packet, "%d;%d;%d;%s", s, 0, numPackets, data); // create packet
```

you would do

```
  sprintf(p->packet, "%d;%d;%d;", s, 0, numPackets);
  memcpy(&p->packet[strlen(p->packet)], data, bytes);
```

but this leads to parsing problems: we would need to change this:

```
tokens = strtok(NULL, ";");

if(tokens != NULL)
strcpy(data, tokens);
```

to something like this:

```
tokens += 1 + ( size < 10 ? 1 : size < 100 ? 2 : size < 1000 ? 3 : size < 10000 ? 4 : 5 );
memcpy(data, tokens, sizeof(data));
```

#Binary Protocol

It's easier to use a binary packet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#pragma push(pack,1)
typedef struct Packet {
    int seq, maxseq, size;
    unsigned short cksum;
    unsigned char payload[]; 
} Packet;
#pragma pop(pack)

typedef struct PacketNode{
    struct PacketNode * next;
    Packet packet;
} PacketNode;


PacketNode * allocPacketNode(int maxPayloadSize) {
    void * ptr = malloc(sizeof(PacketNode) + maxPayloadSize); // FIXME: error checking
    memset(ptr, 0, sizeof(PacketNode) + maxPayloadSize);    // mallocz wouldn't cooperate
    return (PacketNode*) ptr;
}

PacketNode * prepare(FILE * fp, int fsize, int chunksize)
{
    PacketNode * head = allocPacketNode(chunksize);
    PacketNode * pn = head;
    int rd, seq = 0;
    int maxseq = fsize / chunksize + ( fsize % chunksize ? 1 : 0 );

    while ( ( rd = fread(pn->packet.payload, 1, chunksize, fp ) ) > 0 )
    {
        printf("read %d bytes\n", rd);
        pn->packet.seq = seq++;
        pn->packet.maxseq = maxseq;
        pn->packet.size = rd + sizeof(Packet);
        pn->packet.cksum = 0;
        pn->packet.cksum = ~checksum(&pn->packet, pn->packet.size);

        if ( rd == chunksize )
            pn = pn->next = allocPacketNode(chunksize);
    }
        
    return head;
}

int checksum(unsigned char * data, int len)
{
    int sum = 0, i;
    for ( i = 0; i < len; i ++ )
        sum += data[i];
    if ( sum > 0xffff )
        sum = (sum & 0xffff) + (sum>>16);
    return sum;
}

void test( PacketNode * ptr ) {
    FILE *fpNew = fopen("test.jpg", "w");

    while (ptr != NULL) 
    {
        printf("sequence: %d/%d, checksum: %04x, size: %d\n", 
            ptr->packet.seq,
            ptr->packet.maxseq,
            ptr->packet.cksum,
            ptr->packet.size - sizeof(Packet)
        );
        int b = fwrite(ptr->packet.payload, ptr->packet.size - sizeof(Packet), 1, fpNew);

        ptr = ptr->next;
    }

    fclose(fpNew);
}

void fatal( const char * msg ) { printf("FATAL: %s\n", msg); exit(1); }

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if ( ! argv[1] ) fatal( "missing filename argument" );
    FILE * fp = fopen( argv[1], "r" );
    if ( ! fp ) fatal( "cannot open file" );
    fseek( fp, 0, SEEK_END );
    long fsize = ftell(fp);
    fseek( fp, 0, SEEK_SET );
    printf("Filesize: %d\n", fsize );

    test( prepare(fp, fsize, 1024) );
}
```

The `#pragma push(pack,1)` changes how the compiler aligns fields of the struct. We want them to be compact, for network transport. Using `1` is byte-aligned. The `#pragma pop(pack)` restores the previous setting of the [`pack pragma`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure-Packing-Pragmas.html).

**A note on the checksum method**

First we calculate the sum of all the bytes in the packet:

```
    int sum = 0, i;
    for ( i = 0; i < len; i ++ )
        sum += data[i];
```

Since the packet uses an unsigned short (16 bits, max value 65535 or 0xffff) to store the checksum, we make sure that the result will fit:

```
    if ( sum > 0xffff )      // takes up more than 16 bits.
```

Getting the low 16 bits of this int is done using `sum & 0xffff`, masking out everything but the low 16 bits. We could simply return this value, but we would loose the information from higher checksum bits. So, we will add the upper 16 bits to the lower 16 bits. Accessing the higher 16 bits is done by shifting the int to the right 16 bits, like so: `sum >> 16`. This is the same as `sum / 65536`, since 65536 = 2<sup>16</sup> = 1 << 16.

```
        sum = (sum & 0xffff) + (sum>>16);    // add low 16 bits and high 16 bits
```

I should note that [network packet checksums are usually computed](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1071) 2 bytes (or 'octets' as they like to call them there) at a time. For that, the `data` should be cast to an `unsigned short *`, and `len` should be divided by 2. However! `len` may be odd, so in that case we'll need to take special care of the last byte. For instance, assuming that the maximum packet size is even, and that the `len` argument is always `<=` max_packet_size:

```
unsigned short * in = (unsigned short *) data;
if ( len & 1 ) data[len] = 0;   // make sure last byte is 0
len = (len + 1) / 2;
```

The rest of the checksum method can remain the same, except that it should operate on `in` instead of `data`.

Comment: Thank you so much! can you explain #pragma pop(pack) and #pragma push(pack,1)?

Comment: will I also have to do the #pragmas on the receiver side?

Comment: Yes, they should ideally share an `#include` that lays out the protocol packets: the structs. You could leave the `#pragma`'s out, but then the packet size is dependent on the compiler target's machine architecture (32/64 bit) and compiler settings.  Think of the `#pragmas` as *"belonging to the struct"*.

Comment: I'm getting this warning: warning: ignoring #pragma (  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
 #pragma(pack);

Comment: Hm, what compiler are you using? (`gcc --version`) I've run it successfully here ("gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2")

Comment: I'm using gcc compiler:  gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4

Comment: It should be supported: [structure packing pragmas for gcc 4.8.4](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.4/gcc/Structure-Packing-Pragmas.html#Structure-Packing-Pragmas). If you copy/paste my code to a file it should compile and run fine. Are you sure you are using the right syntax: I see `#pragma(pack)` in your comment about the warning. That should be either `#pragma pack(1)` before the struct, or the `#pragma push(pack,1)`/`#pragma pop(pack)` pair around the struct.

Comment: It works now :) thank you very much! one more thing, can you explain your checksum method? I'm confused about sum += data[len]; why is it that we are continuously adding the data at position len.

Comment: Ah, that is a bug, well spotted! I'll update the answer :-)

Comment: Sure - just the checksum method?

Comment: yes the checksum I dont understand bit manipulation that much

Comment: Updated. Hope it makes sense. There's some tutorials on bit manipulation out there, like [this](https://www.hackerearth.com/notes/bit-manipulation/) or [this](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html), and a [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_manipulation) if you're interested.

Comment: thanks again, doesn't the final sum's bits need to be flipped? Thats what I understood from the regular internet checksum algorithm.

Comment: Yes indeed :-) It got lost in an edit; updated ( `pn->packet->cksum = ~checksum(...)`). And you're welcome. Have you been able to transfer a file over the network yet?

Comment: sort of...I'm implementing go-back-n protocol and when I test it on my ubuntu using local host, everything works perfect. But when I test it on mininet with a topology of 2 hosts, the client on host 1 and the server on host 2 I get infinite timeouts after the client receives an ack for the 285th packet. It also works fine when I test it on the same hosts via mininet..